# How to Solve the error of "Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/native""

Tags: node.js, react-native

**I am getting error while I am compling the code**

The error for Bottom Tab Navigator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1xFO.png)

Comment: Try `npm install @react-navigation/native`. The error clearly states the depedency is missing.

Comment: thanks for you help, the thing is solved

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.